# Stuck at Goomba's speed and cancelling animation at game over

Tags: javascript, physics

I'll try to be as precise as possible.

**First Issue:** If you look in the code, I have a `drawObjects` function which calls `collisionDetection` function.

Inside `collisionDetection` if `player(mario)` touches the `object(Goomba)` then game should be over and animation should stop.

However, even on cancelling the animation frame, the animation won't stop somehow.

**Second Issue:** I want to speed up `Objects(Goomba)` but if I try to reduce their `x` position by more than two (i.e. `objects[i].x -= 3` for example), the `object(goomba)` doesn't show at all except for the first one.

So, in this issue what I seek is, is there another better way to speed up goombas?

Code :

```
        var startTime  = 0;
        var rAF;

        var cnv = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx = cnv.getContext("2d");

        var cWidth = cnv.width = window.innerWidth-10;
        var cHeight = cnv.height = window.innerHeight-20;


        var bgImg = new Image();
        var playerImg = new Image();
        var goombaImg = new Image();

        bgImg.src = "images/mariobg.png";
        playerImg.src = "images/mario.png";
        goombaImg.src = "images/goomba.png";

        var game = {
        state : true,
        score : 0
        }

        var player = {
        x : 15,
        y : cHeight-110,
        w : 75,
        h : 75,
        canJump : true,
        xVelocity : 0,
        yVelocity : 0
        }


        var objects = [];
        objects[0]={
        x : cWidth-110,
        y : cHeight-90,
        w : 50,
        h : 50,

        }

        var controller = {
        moveLeft : false,
        moveUp : false,
        moveRight : false,
        keyListener : function(event){
        var keyState = (event.type == 'keydown') ? true : false ;

        switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 37:
        controller.moveLeft = keyState;
        break;

        case 38:
        controller.moveUp = keyState;
        break;

        case 39:
        controller.moveRight = keyState;
        break;
        }
        }

        }




        document.addEventListener('keydown', controller.keyListener);
        document.addEventListener('keyup', controller.keyListener);



        function draw(timestamp){
        //console.log(performance.now);
        ctx.drawImage(bgImg, 0, 0 , cWidth, cHeight);
        drawPlayer();
        drawObjects();
        drawScore();
        drawDevInfo();
        rAF = requestAnimationFrame(draw);
        }


        function drawPlayer(){
        if(controller.moveLeft){
        player.xVelocity -= 0.5;
        }

        if(controller.moveRight){
        player.xVelocity += 0.5;
        }

        if(controller.moveUp && player.canJump == true){
        player.yVelocity -= 25;
        player.canJump = false;

        }


        player.x += player.xVelocity;
        player.y += player.yVelocity;
        player.xVelocity *= 0.95;
        player.yVelocity *= 0.95;
        player.yVelocity += 1.3;


        if(player.y > cHeight-110){
        player.y = cHeight-110;
        player.yVelocity = 0; 
        player.canJump = true;
        }

        if(player.x > cWidth || player.x < 0){
        player.x = 0; 
        }
        ctx.drawImage(playerImg, player.x, player.y, player.w, player.h);
        }

        function drawObjects(){

        for (let i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        ctx.drawImage(goombaImg, objects[i].x, objects[i].y, objects[i].w, objects[i].h);

        objects[i].x-=1;


        //var now = Date.now;

        //timeElapsed = now - startTime;
        //console.log(timeElapsed);

        if(objects[i].x == cWidth/2){
        objects.push({
            x : cWidth-110,
            y : cHeight-90,
            w : 50,
            h : 50 
        });
        }

        collisionDetection(i);        
        }
        }



        function collisionDetection(i){
        if (player.x+player.w > objects[i].x && player.x < objects[i].x+objects[i].w && (player.y+player.h > objects[i].y)) {
        ctx.font = "25px Verdana";
        ctx.fillText("GAME OVER",cWidth/2, cHeight/2 ); 
        drawScore();
        drawDevInfo();
        cancelAnimationFrame(rAF);

        }
        else {
        game.score = game.score + 1;
        }
        }

        function drawScore(){
        ctx.font = "15px Verdana";
        ctx.fillText("Score : "+ game.score, 15, 20);
        ctx.fillStyle="white";
        }

        function drawDevInfo(){
        ctx.font = "15px Verdana";
        ctx.fillText("@KaushikCodeArts - 2019 ", cWidth/2-15, 20 );
        ctx.fillStyle="white";
        }

        //draw();
        rAF = requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve].

Comment: Will this be ok? https://kaushikdev.github.io/X-Runner/

Comment: Well, if it is working, then codereview SE seems to be a place to go to :)

Comment: The [Game Development SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) could be a nice one too.

Comment: I have updated the git example url also(earlier one won't work) : https://kaushikdev.github.io/Mario-Runner/

Comment: I was going to edit your post, but finally I rather ask you to do it. Could you just keep what's related to your current issue?

Comment: Icepickle , Kevin : Do you mean I need to join those communities and get help there?

Comment: Right now, you are indicating issues, so *Code Review SE* mays not be the right place for that (But it did when you was asking to review your code in order to improve it). However, *Game Development* is still in the topic I guess.

Comment: Oops, rather edit your post instead of writing all of this in the comment section. ;) It will be clearer for us.